# Setting the 'capture' attribute of an HTML Form Image Input via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

For one of my projects I have a form containing file inputs (that accept .jpg and .png). I know that I can set the `capture` attribute in the input tag, so that when the button is clicked, instead of showing a file selector, it should directly go to the camera (aimed here at phone/tablet usage). This works well!

It would, for example, look like this:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" capture>
```

Now I would like to dynamically add file inputs to the form with JavaScript, when they press a `Add Another Image` button.

I have gotten this far:

```js
const input = document.createElement('input')
    
input.type = 'file';
input.name = 'image';
input.accept = 'image/jpeg, image/png';

document.getElementById('image-input-container').appendChild(input);
input.click();
```

Is there a way to set the `capture` attribute using JavaScript this way as well?

Comment: Should work like with most other stand-alone attributes - `input.capture = true`?

Comment: @CBroe, I've tried that, but JS just seems to ignore it and not add it to the input at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to set the capture.

```
input.setAttribute("capture", "");
```

The accept attribute should also be set to allow any type of image.

```
input.accept = 'image/*';
```

Comment: While that does add the attribute to the tag correctly, it also adds an empty string as value. My phone/browser (Google Pixel 2XL, using Google Chrome) does not seem to recognize this as a capture input and shows the file interface instead (same as without the `capture` attribute).

Comment: Have you tried setting it to "user" or "environment"?

Comment: Aha! It actually did work with an empty string. The problem was the `accept="image/jpeg, image/png"`. When setting this to `accept="image/*"`, your solution worked well. Thanks!

Comment: @Mithras No problem.